# Error while Fine tuning yolov7 tiny model on google colab pro

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolov7

I am trying to fine tune my yolov7-tiny pytorch model on my custom dataset which contains 40k images on google colab it gives me the error on first epoch

Command

```
!python train.py --batch 16 --cfg cfg/training/yolov7-tiny.yaml --epochs 30 --data        data/custom_data.yaml --weights 'yolov7-tiny.pt' --device 'cpu' --hyp /content/yolov7/data/hyp.scratch.tiny.yaml
```

Error

```
/content/yolov7
2023-11-23 09:41:50.546886: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2023-11-23 09:41:50.546968: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2023-11-23 09:41:50.547001: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-11-23 09:41:50.556142: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-11-23 09:41:51.761396: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
YOLOR  v0.1-128-ga207844 torch 2.1.0+cu118 CPU

Namespace(weights='yolov7-tiny.pt', cfg='cfg/training/yolov7-tiny.yaml', data='data/custom_data.yaml', hyp='/content/yolov7/data/hyp.scratch.tiny.yaml', epochs=30, batch_size=16, img_size=[640, 640], rect=False, resume=False, nosave=False, notest=False, noautoanchor=False, evolve=False, bucket='', cache_images=False, image_weights=False, device='cpu', multi_scale=False, single_cls=False, adam=False, sync_bn=False, local_rank=-1, workers=8, project='runs/train', entity=None, name='exp', exist_ok=False, quad=False, linear_lr=False, label_smoothing=0.0, upload_dataset=False, bbox_interval=-1, save_period=-1, artifact_alias='latest', freeze=[0], v5_metric=False, world_size=1, global_rank=-1, save_dir='runs/train/exp2', total_batch_size=16)
tensorboard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs/train', view at http://localhost:6006/
hyperparameters: lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=0.05, cls=0.5, cls_pw=1.0, obj=1.0, obj_pw=1.0, iou_t=0.2, anchor_t=4.0, fl_gamma=0.0, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.05, copy_paste=0.0, paste_in=0.05, loss_ota=1
wandb: Install Weights & Biases for YOLOR logging with 'pip install wandb' (recommended)

                 from  n    params  module                                  arguments                     
  0                -1  1       928  models.common.Conv                      [3, 32, 3, 2, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
  1                -1  1     18560  models.common.Conv                      [32, 64, 3, 2, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
  2                -1  1      2112  models.common.Conv                      [64, 32, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
  3                -2  1      2112  models.common.Conv                      [64, 32, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
  4                -1  1      9280  models.common.Conv                      [32, 32, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
  5                -1  1      9280  models.common.Conv                      [32, 32, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
  6  [-1, -2, -3, -4]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
  7                -1  1      8320  models.common.Conv                      [128, 64, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
  8                -1  1         0  models.common.MP                        []                            
  9                -1  1      4224  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 10                -2  1      4224  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 11                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 12                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 13  [-1, -2, -3, -4]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 14                -1  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 15                -1  1         0  models.common.MP                        []                            
 16                -1  1     16640  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 17                -2  1     16640  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 18                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 19                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 20  [-1, -2, -3, -4]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 21                -1  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 22                -1  1         0  models.common.MP                        []                            
 23                -1  1     66048  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 24                -2  1     66048  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 25                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 26                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 27  [-1, -2, -3, -4]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 28                -1  1    525312  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 512, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 29                -1  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 30                -2  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 31                -1  1         0  models.common.SP                        [5]                           
 32                -2  1         0  models.common.SP                        [9]                           
 33                -3  1         0  models.common.SP                        [13]                          
 34  [-1, -2, -3, -4]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 35                -1  1    262656  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 256, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 36          [-1, -7]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 37                -1  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 38                -1  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 39                -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample    [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 40                21  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 41          [-1, -2]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 42                -1  1     16512  models.common.Conv                      [256, 64, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 43                -2  1     16512  models.common.Conv                      [256, 64, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 44                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 45                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 46  [-1, -2, -3, -4]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 47                -1  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 48                -1  1      8320  models.common.Conv                      [128, 64, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 49                -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample    [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 50                14  1      8320  models.common.Conv                      [128, 64, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 51          [-1, -2]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 52                -1  1      4160  models.common.Conv                      [128, 32, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 53                -2  1      4160  models.common.Conv                      [128, 32, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 54                -1  1      9280  models.common.Conv                      [32, 32, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 55                -1  1      9280  models.common.Conv                      [32, 32, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 56  [-1, -2, -3, -4]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 57                -1  1      8320  models.common.Conv                      [128, 64, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 58                -1  1     73984  models.common.Conv                      [64, 128, 3, 2, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 59          [-1, 47]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 60                -1  1     16512  models.common.Conv                      [256, 64, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 61                -2  1     16512  models.common.Conv                      [256, 64, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 62                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 63                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 64  [-1, -2, -3, -4]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 65                -1  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 66                -1  1    295424  models.common.Conv                      [128, 256, 3, 2, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 67          [-1, 37]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 68                -1  1     65792  models.common.Conv                      [512, 128, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 69                -2  1     65792  models.common.Conv                      [512, 128, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 70                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 71                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 72  [-1, -2, -3, -4]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 73                -1  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 74                57  1     73984  models.common.Conv                      [64, 128, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 75                65  1    295424  models.common.Conv                      [128, 256, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 76                73  1   1180672  models.common.Conv                      [256, 512, 3, 1, None, 1, LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)]
 77      [74, 75, 76]  1     82076  models.yolo.IDetect                     [25, [[10, 13, 16, 30, 33, 23], [30, 61, 62, 45, 59, 119], [116, 90, 156, 198, 373, 326]], [128, 256, 512]]
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/functional.py:504: UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at ../aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp:3526.)
  return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
Model Summary: 263 layers, 6079932 parameters, 6079932 gradients, 13.4 GFLOPS

Transferred 330/344 items from yolov7-tiny.pt
Scaled weight_decay = 0.0005
Optimizer groups: 58 .bias, 58 conv.weight, 61 other
train: Scanning '/content/drive/MyDrive/combined_data_14sep/combined_data_14sep/train/labels.cache' images and labels... 28588 found, 1 missing, 6 empty, 2 corrupted: 100% 28590/28590 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
val: Scanning '/content/drive/MyDrive/combined_data_14sep/combined_data_14sep/val/labels.cache' images and labels... 6163 found, 2 missing, 0 empty, 1 corrupted: 100% 6165/6165 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

autoanchor: Analyzing anchors... anchors/target = 4.01, Best Possible Recall (BPR) = 0.9997
Image sizes 640 train, 640 test
Using 8 dataloader workers
Logging results to runs/train/exp2
Starting training for 30 epochs...

     Epoch   gpu_mem       box       obj       cls     total    labels  img_size
      0/29        0G   0.07406   0.02084   0.09498    0.1899        44       640:   2% 42/1787 [14:15<3:01:29,  6.24s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
      0/29        0G   0.06949   0.01645   0.08452    0.1705        35       640:   8% 150/1787 [25:10<2:49:18,  6.21s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
      0/29        0G   0.06428   0.01585   0.07459    0.1547        34       640:  17% 295/1787 [39:58<2:37:10,  6.32s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
      0/29        0G    0.0612   0.01587   0.06808    0.1452        53       640:  24% 425/1787 [53:20<2:15:37,  5.97s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB
      0/29        0G   0.06106    0.0159   0.06779    0.1447        55       640:  24% 433/1787 [54:10<2:20:43,  6.24s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB
      0/29        0G    0.0596   0.01599   0.06443      0.14        66       640:  28% 500/1787 [1:00:59<2:16:03,  6.34s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
      0/29        0G   0.05856   0.01605   0.06269    0.1373        65       640:  31% 555/1787 [1:06:34<2:12:26,  6.45s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'ICC Profile': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50
      0/29        0G    0.0559   0.01591   0.05811    0.1299        57       640:  41% 735/1787 [1:24:59<1:46:40,  6.08s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'ICC Profile': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50
      0/29        0G   0.05285   0.01518   0.04852    0.1166        62       640:  66% 1184/1787 [2:12:21<1:06:22,  6.60s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'ICC Profile': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50
      0/29        0G   0.05234   0.01525   0.04795    0.1155        44       640:  71% 1268/1787 [2:22:00<1:00:09,  6.95s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB
      0/29        0G    0.0511   0.01518     0.045    0.1113        78       640:  88% 1574/1787 [2:55:58<24:06,  6.79s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
      0/29        0G   0.05095   0.01517   0.04469    0.1108        52       640:  90% 1611/1787 [3:00:03<21:35,  7.36s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB
      0/29        0G   0.05036   0.01521   0.04345     0.109        41       640: 100% 1787/1787 [3:19:39<00:00,  6.70s/it]
               Class      Images      Labels           P           R      mAP@.5  mAP@.5:.95:  73% 141/193 [11:14<04:08,  4.78s/it]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/yolov7/train.py", line 616, in <module>
    train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
  File "/content/yolov7/train.py", line 415, in train
    results, maps, times = test.test(data_dict,
  File "/content/yolov7/test.py", line 119, in test
    loss += compute_loss([x.float() for x in train_out], targets)[1][:3]  # box, obj, cls
  File "/content/yolov7/utils/loss.py", line 477, in __call__
    t[range(n), tcls[i]] = self.cp
IndexError: index 5283828224 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 25
```

I'm seeking assistance in identifying and resolving this issue. I'm not entirely certain where the root cause lies, but I'm open to suggestions and guidance from experienced individuals.